Multi-level x-axis labels and missing every other axis labels
Here is a MWE.
df <- data.frame(Y = c(1:12),
                 Combination = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6),
                 Treatment = c("AX", "AY", "AY", "AX", 
                               "BZ", "BY", "BZ", "BX", 
                               "BY", "BX", "BX", "BY"),
                 Stage = rep(c(1,2), 6)
                      )

I want to create a bar chart with two levels of x-axis labels. The following is my plotting code:
my_greys_alt <- c("#000000", "#707070", "#000000","#707070", "#CCCCCC")

ggplot(test.df, aes(y = Y, fill = factor(Treatment), x = Combination, group = Stage)) +
   geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='summary', fun='mean', show.legend = T) +
   theme_classic() + 
   scale_fill_manual(values = my_greys_alt)

And the resulting plot is:

The first problem is that I do not know how to add another layer of the x-axis label. I searched for some solutions, but they did not work for me.

On top of the Combination x-axis label, I would like to add Treatment as another layer of the x-axis label, e.g., add AX and AY as labels on top of 1.

The second problem is that:

The x-axis labels for variable Combination are omitted every other tick mark. How can all the tick marks be displayed in the plot?

Thanks a lot for your help.
